# Weighted random using Zipf's distribution curve

Tags: javascript, distribution

I'm looking to construct a JavaScript function that returns random elements but based on Zipf's distribution curve:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law

I had a look at this:
http://codetheory.in/weighted-biased-random-number-generation-with-javascript-based-on-probability/

It's somewhat close, but I'd like to use an approach that is simpler using a mathematical formula that is based on Zipf's distribution curve.

Consider:

```
['kiwi', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'mango', .... etc]
```

So essentially if we picked 10,000 random fruits from above array we would get this distribution:

[image]

Where the first dot is kiwi, the second dot orange and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you want to implement the simplest case of Zipf's law with s=1. That means you can simply take the elements of the harmonic series with `n` the length of your Array and set the weight of the first element of your array to `1`, the next to `1/2`, the next to `1/3` and so on until `1/n` is reached.

You can then just use the code from codetheory and insert your element-weight-array (as a key-value object like they do it there) instead of their array in`random_check` and you are done.

Comment: Exactly. And it works like a charm. Thanks for your reply.